# Trim each 3 words in newline in string (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i want to trim 3 letter on each newline . but when i do split it only split the first line the other newline already gone. Kindly help. Thank you.

This is the code:

```
var mytext = '(1x) test0, (2x) test1, (3x) test2';

var formattedString = mytext.replace(/,/g, '\n');

console.log("FORMATTED STRING", formattedString)

const output = formattedString
    .split('', 4)
    .reduce((o, c) => (o.length === 4 ? `${o}${c}` : `${o}${c}`), '')

console.log("SPLIT", output)
```

Can access the code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mqnkx2uc/14/

I want the output like this:
"(1x) \n
(2x) \n
(3x)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a regex to start by matching a `)`, then match non-`(` characters, and replace with `)\n`:

```js
var mytext = '(1x) test0, (2x) test1, (3x) test2';
console.log(
  mytext.replace(
    /\)[^\(]+/g,
    ')\n'
  )
  .trim()
);
```

Comment: sorry can i ask what if i want to to print test0\ntest1\ntest2? can i ask how will i gonna do that ? sorry

Comment: Depends on the format of the input string, maybe `.match(/\w+(?=,|$)/g).join('\n')`

Comment: is it should be myText.match(/\w+(?=,|$)/g).join('\n') ? sorry again for asking

Comment: It produces the output you want in the comment, so sure, you can use that if you want

Comment: cause i also want to store this test0\ntest1\ntest2 into to new variable. but im not sure how

Comment: Just assign it to something? `const someNewVar = ...`

Comment: yes assign that in a new var but i wanted to remove the (1x)(2x)(3x)

Comment: Yes, the new variable will indeed contain the text without those parentheses

Comment: Thank you this regex is there any sample i can use for guide? Thank you cause some of my text has a space.

Comment: There's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean and lots of tutorials https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much really appreciate it. Thank youuu